# This is the bone of which animal? And which bone?

Tags: species-identification, bone-biology

[image]

[image]

so this bone was found on a construction site in Paris and I was wondering from which animal does it come from?

Comment: Not really a bone guy, but it does have a sortof tibial/carpal look to it. Some kind of ungulate maybe?

Comment: This looks quite large. I don't think it belongs to current french Fauna. Do you know in what geological layer this bone was found? Is it petrified?

Comment: It might be interesting to have information about the history of the site.

Comment: I don't really have any info about the geological layer and whether if it's petrified or not. My only guess is that it's a femur...I'm not really good with bones

Comment: looks like a femur to me. You can see the head and paired distal condyles

Comment: Related? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/62871/identifying-a-lone-bone-found-newar-rowena-crest-oregon-usa?rq=1

Comment: @LinuxBlanket. Thanks for bringing attention to that [other bone ID question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/62871/16866). However, the bone in your linked question is a forelimb bone (the humerus) while the bone in this post looks much more like a femur (a hind-limb bone). The sizes are also drastically different.